# Update current value of ionRangeSlider on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider and I want to make 2 buttons, one to update the value of the slider to the next one, another to update it to the previous one. That is, if the current value is 10, when pressing the button, set it to 9 or 11, depending on the button that is pressed.

I am new to JavaScript and JQuery, sure it is something simple, but I can not find it. I get to update the value, but the slider doesn't move.

This is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#range_slider").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "single",
    min: 75,
    max: 100,
    from: 75,
    step: 1,
    grid: true,
    skin: "flat",
    onChange: update_page,
});

// I have this, I update the value but the onChange of the ionRangeSlider is not executed ...
$("#button_previous").off('click').on('click', function () {
    let a = $("#range_slider").data("ionRangeSlider");
    a.update({
        from: 90,
    });
});

$("#button_next").off('click').on('click', function () {
    // i don't know what to do here
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the script for updating the slider with buttos;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $range = $("#range_slider")
  $range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "single",
    min: 75,
    max: 100,
    from: 75,
    step: 1,
    grid: true,
    skin: "flat"
  });
  
  const instance = $range.data("ionRangeSlider");

  $("#button_next").off('click').on('click', function() {
     instance.update({
            from: instance.result.from + 1
     });
  });

  $("#button_previous").off('click').on('click', function() {
     instance.update({
            from: instance.result.from - 1
     });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding:100px;
}
```

```html
    <!--Plugin CSS file with desired skin-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css"/>
    
    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!--Plugin JavaScript file-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
    
<input type=button id="button_previous" value="<"/>
<input type=button id="button_next" value=">"/>
<br>&nbsp;
<input id="range_slider"/>
```